# An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Spring UAA". org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaModelException in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am new to Spring. 
I have installed from the spring-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e3.8-win32 folder which contains the below folders:

1. apache-maven-3.0.4
2. spring-roo-1.2.2.RELEASE
3. sts-3.1.0.RELEASE
4. vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.2.RELEASE
   I have Eclipse Juno already installed in my system.

**After the installation  of the STS, when I tried to open, it gave the below error:**

An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Spring UAA".
org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaModelException

**Also there was another error as below**:

Could not create the view: Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart.

org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:192)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:323)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:402)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:376)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:111)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:461)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:305)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:218)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:97)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:41)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureGenericSignatureUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:807)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getDeclaredInterfaces(BcelObjectType.java:255)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredInterfaces(ReferenceType.java:624)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:548)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.isAssignableFrom(ReferenceType.java:399)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ExactTypePattern.matchesInstanceof(ExactTypePattern.java:199)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePattern.matches(TypePattern.java:153)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ThisOrTargetPointcut.matchInternal(ThisOrTargetPointcut.java:124)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndPointcut.matchInternal(AndPointcut.java:51)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndPointcut.matchInternal(AndPointcut.java:51)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndPointcut.matchInternal(AndPointcut.java:51)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndPointcut.matchInternal(AndPointcut.java:51)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ShadowMunger.match(ShadowMunger.java:113)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Advice.match(Advice.java:109)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelAdvice.match(BcelAdvice.java:146)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:3125)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.matchInvokeInstruction(BcelClassWeaver.java:3073)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:2774)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.matchInit(BcelClassWeaver.java:2592)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:2514)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:473)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:99)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1674)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1618)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1379)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1173)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:467)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.loadtime.OSGiWeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj.AspectJWeavingService.preProcess(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.adaptors.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hooks.WeavingHook.processClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.ViewDescriptor.createView(ViewDescriptor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActivationList.setActive(WorkbenchPage.java:4321)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$18.runWithException(WorkbenchPage.java:3363)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1600)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2609)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? There are a number of bundles / packagings and versions of STS, and different ways to install it (from a zip, update site or Eclipse marketplace). So what exactly did you try to run and how?

Comment: This looks like a broken installation to me. Can you unzip the distribution package again and start fresh?

Comment: If martin is right and something got messed in unzip, then possible to blame is the unzip program used. I have heard several cases that some Windows unzip programs can not deal properly with long path names in a zip and result in corrupt installations. Try a different zip program (maybe this http://www.7-zip.org/) also try unzipping to a short directory Like C:\STS. Some version of Windows OS don't support long path names and this also can cause corruption.

Comment: Thanks Martin and Kris...Reinstalltion worked from a different zip folder.